# Problems with csrf-token and login on Scrapy

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, web-crawler

Currently I'm trying to crawl a page which needs to have a session indicated in order to let me get some information. For that purpose I have created a simple Python program using the Scrapy library, but I'm not completely sure if it is developed correctly since I don't know how to debug it (or if is this even possible) right now I'm not getting any results.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from strava_crawler.items import StravaCrawlerItem
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class stravaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'stravaSpider'
    item_count = 0
    allowed_domain = ['https://www.strava.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.strava.com/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath("//meta[@name='csrf-token']/@content").extract_first()
        print(token)
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
            'username': 'xxxx@xxx.com',
            'password': 'xxxxx',
            'authenticity_token': token
        }, callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        sc_item = StravaCrawlerItem()
        sc_item['titulo'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="athlete-name"]/text()').extract()
        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count == 1:
            raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        yield sc_item
```

The code seems pretty simple as you can see but my problem comes in 2 points of it. The first one is on the:

```
token = response.xpath("//meta[@name='csrf-token']/@content").extract_first()
```

Which I'm not really sure about, I have looked the html from the page and this is what I found:
[image: token]

My second problem comes with the network header from the own page, which looks like this:
[image: header]

Which make me doubt about my FormRequest.from_response, I have seen solutions using the csrf-token in the own from_response, but I have tried and haven't gotten any response either. This is the return I get on the terminal which I can suppose could be interesting for the question.
[image: return]

Do you see something wrong on the code or the concept of the program?

EDIT: after a few changes I get a new output which looks like a redirect loop imo, in which I get redirected from the dashboard to the login. I print the response.body and it´s the html code of the login page.
[image: return_edit]

EDIT2: I ran the code in Ubuntu (I was on windows) and worked perfectly. So feel free to use it as example of scrapy logging.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need to get the token yourself, the FormRequest.from_response fills it in for you. You can test this in scrapy shell like this:

```
>>> from scrapy import FormRequest
>>> req = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
...             'username': 'xxxx@xxx.com',
...             'password': 'xxxxx',
...         })
>>> req.body
b'utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=L4mSH2wLcNAiLcR7yqCb%2BEdaNyPyJqU%2BbbT1ct9wQGWPnqstXVM5bWX1tmIPq62qpp4FpHdsjazlruVe%2Ba0xpg%3D%3D&plan=&email=&username=xxxx%40xxx.com&password=xxxxx'
```

- You use 'username', but if you check the request done when you login, they use 'email'.
- I don't think it gives problems here, but it's usually good to specify the form and the submit (to avoid filling in a wrong form, or clicking a wrong button like 'reset password).

I would try to test it like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formid="login_form",
        clickdata={'type': 'submit'},
        formdata={
              'email': 'xxxx@xxx.com',
              'password': 'xxxxx',
        },
        callback=self.start_scraping)
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. I just tried it and doesnt seems like working neither... I didn´t even change the terminal return. Dunno, i will keep trying.

Comment: Strange - created an account and the above code works for me. Are you sure it's not just what you do in 'parse' that is incorrect? I end up on this part of the website (https://www.strava.com/athlete/consents/welcome), which doesn't seem to have the information available that you try to get. You can also just share the logs after these changes so we can look further into it.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the delay, i didnt see the notification till a few minutes ago. I will edit the question so u can share the logs in order we can check what's going on. Thanks a lot and sorry again